# python spyder-ide switching between split windows

Tags: python-3.x, spyder

I work on spyder using split windows side by side, how to switch between them using a keyboard shortcut because now I have to go back to mouse to switch the windows.

Comment: Have you done any googling for the issue? Check this out: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/1741

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) We're working to improve this in Spyder 4 (to be released next year). For now, there's no shortcuts to switch between detached panes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, by the way, for now, I just opened a new window and I can switch by alt-tab.